# MySQL Stored Procedure Generating an Error during creation

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a MySQL stored procedure (shown below) that's supposed to build a list of IDs from a table of hierarchically related items. I'm having to re-engineer the stored procedure to switch from using a simple `CONCAT` function to `GROUP_CONCAT` because the former couldn't handle the size of the lists being generated (i.e., the lists are becoming well over the 1024 character limit).

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SPTest (top_id INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE ids_all TEXT;
    SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 100000;
    SET ids_all = top_id;
    SET str = GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR \', \') ',
        'FROM tbl WHERE nha_id = ', top_id, ' INTO @ids_tmp' SEPARATOR '');
    PREPARE stmt FROM str;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    WHILE @ids_tmp != "" DO
        SET ids_all = GROUP_CONCAT(ids_all, @ids_tmp SEPARATOR ', ');
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('All IDs collected thus far: "', ids_all, '"' SEPARATOR '');
        SET str = GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR \', \') ',
            'FROM tbl WHERE nha_id IN (', @ids_tmp, ') INTO @ids_tmp' SEPARATOR '');
        PREPARE stmt FROM str;
        EXECUTE stmt;
    END WHILE;
    SELECT ids_all AS ids;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

This routine was working fine with CONCAT, but now it's generating the following errors and I can't figure out what's wrong:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE ids_all TEXT;
    SET ids_all = top_id;
    SET str = GROUP_CONCAT('SE' at line 4
```

I've tried it both with and without a leading "@" sign in front of the `ids_all` variable. I also tried it with different `DELIMITER` characters (as suggested in other posts here), but they made no difference. The MySQL Error Message Reference says it's some kind of a "Parse Error", but I don't understand what that means or what I can do about it. Can anyone provide any insight into what I'm missing? FYI, I'm using MySQL 8.0 on an Ubuntu Linux server, and running this directly in the CLI database client (not through PHP, yet).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the `str` variable needed an '@' symbol for the SQL to be considered 'ok'. This is very weird considering I have 2 other Stored Procedures very similar to this one (in fact, one of them was the starting point for this script) that I created under MySQL 8.0 literally **the day before** I ran into the problem I described above, and those scripts ran completely error-free and the Stored Procedures work perfectly (except for the string length problem I described above).

So the modified script looks like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SPTest (top_id INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE ids_all TEXT;
    SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
    SET ids_all = top_id;
    SET @str = GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR \', \') ',
        'FROM tbl WHERE nha_id = ', top_id, ' INTO @ids_tmp' SEPARATOR '');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    WHILE @ids_tmp != "" DO
        SET ids_all = GROUP_CONCAT(ids_all, @ids_tmp SEPARATOR ', ');
        SET @str = GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR \', \') ',
            'FROM tbl WHERE nha_id IN (', @ids_tmp, ') INTO @ids_tmp' SEPARATOR '');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
        EXECUTE stmt;
    END WHILE;
    SELECT ids_all AS ids;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

This now runs and creates the Stored Procedure with no SQL syntax errors. However, I'm currently getting a different error:

```
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
```

but that'll be the subject of a separate question if I can't find a solution.